# How can I use KDE on Ubuntu, except with the Gnome shell login?

Tags: 18.04, kde, gnome-shell

I don't know much about Linux and I'm unsure if this is possible. I don't want to risk my system.

[EDIT]

I want to keep the default login screen, but use the KDE desktop environment. I have seen from other posts that you need a different window manager to use KDE, which also changes the login screen.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean and remove irrelevant information from the body of your question.

Comment: You want to use the KDE desktop environment but keep the GNOME login screen?

Comment: @dlin yes, i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Kubuntu package by

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^
```

and then set GDM as default by

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm # choose gdm here
```

Comment: After following this advice, I found that I now cannot login via the default desktop, only through Wayland and KDE isn't even listed. I ran ```sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop``` and ```sudo apt autoremove```. How do I fix it?

Comment: You have to try reinstallation of GDM3 with `sudo apt-get install gdm3 --reinstall`.

Comment: It still won't work - after I press sign in, it just takes me back to the user selector.

Comment: Which desktop do you want to use on daily way?

Comment: I would prefer KDE, but I also need the default, **not wayland** desktop.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^ sddm`

Comment: Wil this fix the problem of not being able to access the default desktop?

Comment: What is the `^` for in `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^ sddm`? BTW, even in Kubuntu 20.04, Wayland isn't supported by default. To get a Wayland session going in Kubuntu, one has to install at least one extra package.

Comment: @DKBose `^` means package installation task as it would be installed using [`tasksel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/tasksel.8.html). Your help may be very appreciated here, I'm a bit stuck what is really happens on OP system.

Comment: @N0rbert, I mostly don't suggest mixing GNOME and KDE desktop environments. While some people have been successful, quite a few have bad experiences. I guess OP may have to login via a virtual terminal and remove SDDM from there and set GDM3 as the display manager. In OP's latest question, they just want to get back to regular Ubuntu!

Comment: After fiddling, I have decide that it would be easier to just use SDDM.