# How to fix GDM3 loop?

Tags: 18.04, gdm

After following advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233448/1075339), I have found myself stuck in a loop. Only the Wayland version works, but I need the normal edition. I no longer care about getting KDE, I just want my laptop fixed. It has an old Nvidia Quadro 2013 if that helps.

Comment: Mixing desktop environments *may* have unpredictable consequences. Experienced users may be able to handle any complications. Inexperienced users may need a lot of hand-holding.

Comment: Are you sure "only the Wayland version works"? How do you know you're in a Wayland session?

Comment: I know that I'm in wayland because that's what I chose on the login screen and what I'm typing this on.

Comment: So what do you mean by "GDM3 loop"?

Comment: I mean that when I press 'Sign In' it takes me back to the user selection page.

Answer (score 1):

I found that running `sudo apt uninstall kubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt autoremove` and then rebooting seemed to fix the problem. I still don't have KDE, but I don't want to risk my PC trying. I also added gnome tweaks, I don't know if this made any difference.